# My Search button text does not align to the button

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, submit

This is the Submit Button on my website:

```
<input type="submit" class="myticket-schedule-btn" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'myticket' ) ?>">
```

Here's the image:
[The Search Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjeUT.png)

Why does it not appear in the middle? How can I edit it to align it in the middle vertically?
I have tried input `style="vertical-align: middle;"` and `style="text-align: center;"` and both do not work.

Comment: can you please post the css that is applied to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added padding: 0px; and it was resolved.

```
<input type="submit" class="myticket-schedule-btn" style="padding: 0px;" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'myticket' ) ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any height from the input and use padding for the input. 
For example...
.myticket-schedule-btn {padding:10px 20px;}